# Voice over accessibility paging problems for scroll view with content inset

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

Consider the following scenario: A `UIScrollView` with content inset of top: 500. In this area there is a subview.

When "three finger swiping" to go "to the next page" of the scroll view, the `UIScrollView` insists that it should never scroll above it's content offset 0. Sometimes it actually scrolls there and says (Page ZERO of 3), but after a while it never jumps there. Is there any way of also including the "content inset" area in the page scrolling?

Here is some test code that replicates this behaviour. Our actual user case is more complex but this is the basic idea:
https://gist.github.com/ullstrm/45bd68032fe92ba13476b506ed70f424

The View Controller has just a single scroll view with all edges constrained to superview with constant 0.

Any ideas of how to let iOS know that it should scroll to this area as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override Voiceover's scrolling behavior using the [`accessibilityScroll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615161-accessibilityscroll?language=objc) method. You'll need to manually change `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset`, but otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! For clarity, if you return "true" from this function you tell iOS that you've handled the action. If you return "false", it propagates to the ancestors and are ultimately handled by iOS.